# Setting id attribute from json data

Tags: objective-c

so I'm trying to set the id attribute of an object to some json data I get back from an HTTP request.  My response is structured as follows:

`{"work":
    {"id": 1, 
     "name": "dave"}}`

This response is set in an NSDictionary.  In order to set this data to one of my classes, I use:

```
user.work.id = dictionary[@"work"].id;
```

but this gives an error because of the "id".  I'm confused at how to set this attribute to an object of my own class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `dictionary[@"work"].id` is that you're trying to use dot notation on an object of type 'id' - so the compiler doesn't know that it's valid. And it isn't valid, because the 'id' is actually a key in a nested dictionary. So, you should be doing:

```
user.work.id = dictionary[@"work"][@"id"];
```

Or

```
user.work.id = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"work.id"];
```

Comment: `user.work.id` is still not good. Not sure if it's allowed (I hope it's a compiler error!), but it's bad practice nevertheless.

Comment: I agree that it's terrible naming, but I think it is legal. I'd like to see it raise a compile error to stop people doing it too. Renaming to something like `identity` would be preferable.